# re.split - Leave matched string in place?

Tags: python, regex

If this is drop-dead simple or a duplicate, please let me know.  I couldn't find an answer for this here already.

Python's re.split will hack up a string and return a list of strings split by the parameter its sent.  If the search string is in parenthesis, it will preserve the matched string, **but it will put the matched string in a separate list element.**

Is there a way to have re.split simply leave the matched string in place?

For example:

```
swars = """Name:  Chewie  Race:  Wookie    Name:  Han Solo  Race: Human
Name:  Jabba the Hutt  Race: Hutt"""
```

If I want to break this string up in to name entries, I'd use re.split("(Name:)", swars) but what results is a list that looks something like:

```
('Name:', 'Chewie  Race:  Wookie', 'Name:', 'Han Solo  Race: Human', 'Name:', 'Jabba the Hutt  Race: Hutt')
```

When what I want is:

```
('Name: Chewie  Race:  Wookie', 'Name: Han Solo  Race: Human', 'Name: Jabba the Hutt  Race: Hutt')
```

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use regex with lookahead `\s*(?=Name)` in order to split the string and keep the "Name":

```
import re

swars = """Name:  Chewie  Race:  Wookie    Name:  Han Solo  Race: Human
Name:  Jabba the Hutt  Race: Hutt"""

print re.split('\s*(?=Name)', swars) 
# prints: ['Name:  Chewie  Race:  Wookie', 'Name:  Han Solo  Race: Human', 'Name:  Jabba the Hutt  Race: Hutt']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   \s+(?=Name)
```

Split by this.Essentially it says split by spaces followed by name.